# How do I check if a number that's been inputted is in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

This is the code I have so far but it never recognizes the first if statement. For example if I input 3, the variable yon stays as 0 and does not change to 1.

```
int yon = 0;
int[] newNums = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
System.out.print("Enter a number:");
int userNum = scan.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i<newNums.length; i++){
  if (userNum == newNums[i]){
    yon = 1;
  }else if (userNum != newNums[i]){
    yon = 0;
  }
}
if (yon==1){
  System.out.println("That number was in the array.");
}else if (yon == 0){
  System.out.println("That number was not in the array.");
}
```

Comment: Hi. You are missing a language tag in the question. Please [edit] .

Answer (score 3):

You should use **break** inside the loop. It will stop the flow after the input is found in the array so it won't go to the `else` block and set `yon = 0` in later iterations.

In fact, the `else` block can be deleted. There's no need to do anything if the number doesn't match.

```
int yon = 0;
int[] newNums = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
System.out.print("Enter a number:");
int userNum = scan.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i<newNums.length; i++){
  if (userNum == newNums[i]){
    yon = 1;
    break;
  }
}
if (yon==1){
  System.out.println("That number was in the array.");
}else if (yon == 0){
  System.out.println("That number was not in the array.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A good approach is to modularise your code by using a method to "name" a chunk of code that does something, in this case working out if an array *contains* a value:

```
private static boolean contains(int[] array, int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then your code can be [refactored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) to be more readable:

```
int[] newNums = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
System.out.print("Enter a number:");
int userNum = scan.nextInt();
if (contains(newNums, userNum)) {
    System.out.println("That number was in the array.");
} else {
    System.out.println("That number was not in the array.");
}
```

Doing this also makes testing and debugging easier, which is important as things get more complex.